# How is the circuit getting power

Tags: pi-3

In the pic, I have connected `GPIO 17` to `resistor`, which connects to an `led` which connects to the ground. The `rasberry pi` is connected to the board via the ribbon. I have not explicitly connected the power `pins 2,4` to the GPIO, resistor, LED circuit. How is the circuit getting power?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will get power from the power supply you have plugged in to the Pi.

As long as the Pi is powered 3V3 will be supplied to pins 1 and 17 and 5V will be supplied to pins 2 and 4.

The GPIO will also receive power from the 3V3 supply.  Each GPIO also has internal pulls.  Some GPIO default to pulls to 3V3, others default to pulls to ground.

GPIO 17 default to pull low.  If it is lit this suggests the other end of the circuit is connected to 3V3.  If that's not the case then you must have set GPIO 17 as a high output.

Comment: Thanks. I suppose you mean that 3V3 will be supplied to physical pin 17. GPIO 17 maps to physical pin 11.